# Catch data from open.window blocked by chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oauth, oauth-2.0, popupwindow

I need to open an authentication window..

On load, I'm calling **window.open**
(Pay attention that there is no user's click to trigger the window.open)

In Chrome, if window.open wasn't triggered by a user action, popup is blocked. there is an icon in the URL saying that popup has been blocked: [image].

If user clicks on this icon the popup will open but **window.open** returns null. So there is no way to *link* the **window.open** to the **opener**
I would like to send the token to the opener on close.

Is there a way to get the opened window for that use case?

Comment: is the popup on the same domain as the page? you can push a ref from the popup if not: `opener.popup=window;`

Comment: popup on the same domain. How can I push a ref? window.open returns NULL.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=485376. Anyway is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I did it wrong.
I simply add a listener to localStorage

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
  if (e.key === "access_token" && e.newValue) 
    store.dispatch('onLoggedIn', e.newValue)
  else if(!e.key)
    store.dispatch('onTokenInValid', e.newValue)
})
```

In The popup I'm setting the access_token into localStorage and the opener listening to it